# Python: Convert list of dictionaries to list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to convert a list of dictionaries to list of lists.

From this.

```
d = [{'B': 0.65, 'E': 0.55, 'C': 0.31},
     {'A': 0.87, 'D': 0.67, 'E': 0.41},
     {'B': 0.88, 'D': 0.72, 'E': 0.69},
     {'B': 0.84, 'E': 0.78, 'A': 0.64},
     {'A': 0.71, 'B': 0.62, 'D': 0.32}]
```

To

```
[['B', 0.65, 'E', 0.55, 'C', 0.31],
 ['A', 0.87, 'D', 0.67, 'E', 0.41],
 ['B', 0.88, 'D', 0.72, 'E', 0.69],
 ['B', 0.84, 'E', 0.78, 'A', 0.64],
 ['A', 0.71, 'B', 0.62, 'D', 0.32]]
```

I can acheive this output from

```
l=[]
for i in range(len(d)):
    temp=[]
    [temp.extend([k,v]) for k,v in d[i].items()]
    l.append(temp)
```

**My question is**:

- Is there any better way to do this?
- Can I do this with list comprehension?

Comment: What version of python? Does order matter? You could also use `itertools.chain` - `[list(chain.from_iterable(x.items())) for x in d]`

Comment: @pault  My python version is 3.6.7 and order is matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using python 3.6.7 and [python dictionaries are insertion ordered in python 3.6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6), you can achieve the desired result using `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

print([list(chain.from_iterable(x.items())) for x in d])
#[['B', 0.65, 'E', 0.55, 'C', 0.31],
# ['A', 0.87, 'D', 0.67, 'E', 0.41],
# ['B', 0.88, 'D', 0.72, 'E', 0.69],
# ['B', 0.84, 'E', 0.78, 'A', 0.64],
# ['A', 0.71, 'B', 0.62, 'D', 0.32]]
```

Comment: Thanks for response and note. So if I use python version < 3.7, I have to use `chain` to make sure it arrange in order?

Comment: No, below 3.6 dictionaries are not guaranteed to maintain order. You'd have to use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) in older versions. `chain` here is just used to [flatten the tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/5858851) returned by `items`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
result = [[i for b in c.items() for i in b] for c in d]
```

Output:

```
[['B', 0.65, 'E', 0.55, 'C', 0.31], 
 ['A', 0.87, 'D', 0.67, 'E', 0.41], 
 ['B', 0.88, 'D', 0.72, 'E', 0.69], 
 ['B', 0.84, 'E', 0.78, 'A', 0.64], 
 ['A', 0.71, 'B', 0.62, 'D', 0.32]]
```

Comment: This seems what the OP is asking for, just a note that the order of `items()` is not deterministic and may change depending on the data and the run.

Answer (score 1):

using lambda this can be done as

```
d = [{'B': 0.65, 'E': 0.55, 'C': 0.31},
     {'A': 0.87, 'D': 0.67, 'E': 0.41},
     {'B': 0.88, 'D': 0.72, 'E': 0.69},
     {'B': 0.84, 'E': 0.78, 'A': 0.64},
     {'A': 0.71, 'B': 0.62, 'D': 0.32}]

d1=list(map(lambda x: [j for i in x.items() for j in i], d))
print(d1)
"""
output

[['B', 0.65, 'E', 0.55, 'C', 0.31],
 ['A', 0.87, 'D', 0.67, 'E', 0.41],
 ['B', 0.88, 'D', 0.72, 'E', 0.69],
 ['B', 0.84, 'E', 0.78, 'A', 0.64],
 ['A', 0.71, 'B', 0.62, 'D', 0.32]]

"""
```